Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
I initialized Firebase inside main, and I need to access user data inside workmanager to provide the user with personalized notification, but workmanager for some reason works synchronously at the same time as Firebase initialization, so it caused this problem.
I tried to add a simple if statement like this to solve the problem and add the initialization twice, one for the main and one for the work manager, but it did not solve the issue.
The output was start firebase initialization printed twice and this error:
lStateException: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!, IllegalStateException, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!
 // AuthService code
 // initialize firebase
        static Future initializeFirebase() async {
          if (!isInitialized && Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
            print('start firebase initializion');
            await Firebase.initializeApp(
              options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
            );
            isInitialized = true;
          } else {
            print('firebase is already initialized');
          }
        }
    ...
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //here is main code:

      Future<void> main() async {
        // initialize firebase
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        await AuthService.initializeFirebase();

        // preferred screen orientations
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
            [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

        // initialize notifications
        NotificationService().initNotification();

        //initialize workmanager
        Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);

      ...



      void callbackDispatcher() async {
        print('entered...');
        // initialize firebase
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        await AuthService.initializeFirebase();

        //////////// access data for notification ////////////////
        final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        String uid = user!.uid;
        //child collection
        final CollectionReference childCollection =
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('child');

        //morning collection
        CollectionReference schedule_morning =
            childCollection.doc(uid).collection('schedule_morning');
        final QuerySnapshot morning_tasks = await schedule_morning.get();

        //noon collection
        CollectionReference schedule_noon =
            childCollection.doc(uid).collection('schedule_noon');
        final QuerySnapshot noon_tasks = await schedule_noon.get();

        //night collection
        CollectionReference schedule_night =
            childCollection.doc(uid).collection('schedule_night');
        final QuerySnapshot night_tasks = await schedule_night.get();

        //to get user name
        final DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await childCollection.doc(uid).get();
        if (userDoc.exists) {
          Map<String, dynamic> userData = userDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          final String userName = userData['name']; 

      // notify the user
      if (DateTime.now().hour == 06 && morning_tasks.size > 0) {
            Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) {
              NotificationService().showNotification(
                title: 'todays tasks',
                body: '$userName do not forget your morning tasks',
              );
              return Future.value(true);
            });
          }
...



Can't you check if firebase is initialized with a simple boolean flag?. Just use  a flag if firebase is not Initialized, initialize the firebase and set the flag to true. if(! initialize) {initialize=true; //and initialize the firebase}.use this inside initializeFirebase() fn.

The point I was trying to make is not to check initialization. I was trying to create a lock to not get Firebase initialization twice, and you may think, Why not just remove the workmanger initialization code and leave the main code? But this error arose. Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created. I think  workmanger did not wait for initialization; it seemed to work at the same time as initialization. That's why this message on my code, "start firebase initializion" was printed twice.

UPDATED ANSWER
Can you try by initializing Firebase in the executeTask method like below.
Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  return Future.value(true);
});

OLD ANSWER
How to setup up Firebase using FlutterFire?
First thing is that you do not have to manually check if firebase is initialized. So just call this function once.
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

To fix your issue run these commands from your project root folder,
flutter pub add firebase_core firebase_messaging

# Install the CLI if not already done so
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

# Run the `configure` command, select a Firebase project and platforms
flutterfire configure

For more information visit this link.

This error arose. Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() so maybe workmanager works at the at the same time with initialization. I think that the problem is not with the initialization setup because it used to work before adding the workmanager data retrieval code.

I have updated the answer. Can you try this new change?

thanks Alish but that did not work i still encounter the same issue No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
